# como faço para detectar em qual lado esta o objeto se eu traçar uma liha o meio

Tags: python, opencv

Meus amigos, estou descobrindo visao computacional. Eu estou programado em python
e queria saber como eu faço para indentificar em que posição o objeto esta em relação a um linha traçada no meio da tela.
Sendo mais direto, se uma reta esta no meio da tela como eu faço para saber se o objeto detectado esta na esquerda ou na direita?

Comment: Já tem algum código escrito que possa mostrar?

Comment: A criação de um [mcve] com imagens e código ajudaria a sua pergunta a ser respondida.

Answer (score 1):

## Caso geral 2D:

Primeiramente vamos considerar alguns parâmetros.

- A linha é vertical e definida pelos pontos A e B
- O objeto estão inteiramente de um lado ou de outro lado da linha
- Você possui a informação de algum ponto P pertencente ao objeto

Para definir o lado em que o objeto se encontra, relizamos o produto vetorial entre o vetores definidos por [image: AB] e [image: AP]:

[image: cross]

onde:

- [image: xab]
- [image: xap]
- [image: yab]
- [image: yap]

O resultado do produto vetorial para duas dimensões, pode retornar um valor negativo, positivo ou nulo. Se for nulo, o ponto P em questão está em cima da linha. Para o caso positivo e negativo, um deles estará de um lado da linha e o outro caso estará do outro lado da linha.

Em Python esse produto pode ser calculado da seguinte forma:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,2])
B = np.array([5,7])
P = np.array([3,4])

res = np.cross(B-A, P-A)
```

Saída:

```
array(-2)
```

Para o caso específico acima, temos que o ponto P está do lado direito da linha definida por [image: AB].

## Caso específico (linha vertical)

Em uma situação mais simples em que a linha separadora é vertical, só há a necessidade de compararmos a coordenda `x` dos objetos em relação à linha.

Caso a coordenada `x` do ponto P escolhido do objeto seja maior do que a coordenada `x` da linha, este objeto se encontra a direita da linha. Caso seja menor, se encontra a esquerda. Caso seja igual, o ponto está em cima da linha